# Invalid Encoding while installing Enthought on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: encoding, installation, ubuntu-14.04, enthought, canopy

I've seen a few instances of this question, but have not found a solution or explanation.

I downloaded the latest canopy express (canopy-1.5.2-rh5-64.sh) onto a 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04.1 installation.  Ran the install successfully.  I then attempted to execute canopy for the first time but received this error:

~/Canopy/canopy_cli setup ~/canopy
/home/barry/Canopy/bin/_python: 1: /home/barry/Canopy/bin/_python: ELF: not found
/home/barry/Canopy/bin/_python: 9: /home/barry/Canopy/bin/_python: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

I also tried executing from the canopy icon from the file browser which produced this file:

�@@�C@8@ (invalid encoding)

It appears that the _python executable cannot be executed due to invalid encoding.

Has anyone else encountered this with Ubuntu 14.04, and is there a work-around?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely cause: trying to install 64-bit Canopy on 32-bit Linux.

What is the output of `uname -m` ?

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/361013/canopy-ide-unexpected-error